# How do I create/manage the stuff on private IP address of a device connected to LAN?

Tags: networking, wifi, lan

Okay. I really didn't know how to explain the question in title. What I actually want to do is this:

Suppose a device is connected to WiFi, i.e. it's on LAN. It would have a private IP address like 192.168.xx.xx like that. What I want is my (android app/or technically general way) program to have access to that IP and display some info on it, like a webpage or maybe live screen of the device itself?

For ex: http://192.168.0.105:5901/thisScreen would stream live screen of a mobile device. This URL can opened by any device connected to LAN. How do I achieve that streaming access on that particular IP address assigned to the device? (Assume I've control to everything).

How do I even begin for this? Networking? How do I implement it? Any references? I tried to Google my problem but didn't find any help.

Comment: Is there a particular programming language you intend to use to create your application?

Comment: I'm specifically targeting android, say like mirroring display of android device on a url like http://192.168.0.105:5901/thisScreen which would then be accessible by any device on LAN

Comment: I understand that, but my question is about the programming language you would like to use to write your program.

Comment: Java, for android @RonMaupin

Comment: Do you have any code to share? What have you tried, and where does it fail?

Comment: I'm open to PHP as well, if that might be needed in setting something else I'm missing right now @RonMaupin

Comment: @RonMaupin That's what I'm asking. I have no idea how to begin with this implementation. I've just seen some apps doing this and I tried to decompile the app to read its code, unfortunately, its kinda mess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124341/discussion-between-mehul-mohan-and-ron-maupin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you ask **in general**, what you want is to serve sth on a lan ip ex: on 192.168.1.50:80 and that is available to everyone on the same lan to be precise in 192.168.1.0/24 right?

Well if you haven't done any configuration such as subnets smaller than /24 that is what happening **by default**.

To confirm that run a web server an nginx for example on a local machine and visit the ip of this machine from another device on the same lan, you will see the default page of nginx.

So the only thing you have to configure is a service to run on a local machine and serves sth.